# The event for middle mouse down and move

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the [control event](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Articles/ArticleListing.aspx?SectionID=1&SubSectionID=77) for middle mouse down and move? That is, what is the event that I can subscribed to when I hold my middle mouse down and move the mouse?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at

- [Control.MouseDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown(VS.71).aspx)
- [MouseButton Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebutton.aspx)
- [Detecting Mouse Button Events in C#](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/mouse/article.php/c6133/)

You can also try something like this

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
    {
        label1.Text = String.Format("{0} :: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
    }
}
```